# Cannot install python package due to cmake error

Tags: python, cmake, pip

I am trying to install the disptools package by doing `pip install disptools` in my terminal.
The disptools package is linked here https://github.com/m-pilia/disptools.
It gives me a long error message during the installation with the main error displayed below.

```
Building wheel for disptools (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

...

CMake Error:

Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES)`
```

It also includes this in the error:

```
File "/Users/name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '/private/var/folders/6p/16591qb93vs76dysmldcz8140000gn/T/pip-install-vn5twf6v/disptools', '-DDISPTOOLS_DEBUG=OFF', '-DDISPTOOLS_OPT=OFF', '-DDISPTOOLS_VERBOSE=ON', '-DDISPTOOLS_LOW_ORDER_PD=OFF', '-DDISPTOOLS_DOUBLE=OFF', '-DDISPTOOLS_CUDA_SUPPORT=OFF', '-DDISPTOOLS_CUDA_ERROR_CHECK=ON', '-DDISPTOOLS_CUDA_ERROR_CHECK_SYNC=ON', '-DDISPTOOLS_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON', '-DDISPTOOLS_PYTHON_C_MODULE_NAME=_disptools', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=/private/var/folders/6p/16591qb93vs76dysmldcz8140000gn/T/pip-install-vn5twf6v/disptools/build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6', '-DCMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/Users/name/anaconda3/bin/python3']' 
returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I have looked everywhere online but I couldn't really find any helpful resources for solving this problem.
Would really appreciate it if someone can help.

Comment: Why not use [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) to install it for you? `python -m pip install disptools`

Comment: I tried doing `python -m pip install disptools` but it gives the same error

Answer (score 1):

With commands, `python -m pip install disptools` you try to download, compile and install the `disptools`.

Compilation step fails with a `CMake` error that tell that it failed to find library `OpenMP`. You can install it on a Ubuntu/Debian distribution with

```sh
sudo apt install libomp-dev
```

After this, you can launch again the `pip` command.

I hope you will meet all compilation requirements.

Comment: If the same error occurs with MacOS, then you have to install openmp with brew for example

Comment: I did brew install libomp and that solved the error. 

Another error came up after that and I am not sure how to solve it.

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Anaconda Prompt (recommended),

conda install -c conda-forge dlib